# Auto colour numbers in range

Tags: tables, color, conditionals

If I had some numbers in a tabular column, is there a way to automatically change the font colour of them if they are outside a range; eg red if under 10 and green if over 50?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  5 \\
  20 \\
  60
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect the cell entry using [`collcell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) and condition on it's value with a basic `\ifnum` TeX condition:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell,array,xcolor}
\newcommand{\formatcolentry}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<10 \color{red}%
  \else\ifnum#1>30 \color{green}%
  \fi\fi#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\collectcell\formatcolentry}c<{\endcollectcell}}
   5 \\
  20 \\
  60
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```